# Adding maximum values from different levels to a new column in a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, apply

I have a following R problem. I made an experiment and observed some cars speed. I have a table with cars (where number 1 means for example Porche, 2 Volvo and so on) and their speeds. One car could been taken into an observation more than once. So, for example, Porche was observed tree times, Volvo two times.

`exp<-data.frame(car=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),speed=c(10,20,30,40,50,60))`

I would like to add a third column, where for every row/every car the maximum speed is calculated. So it looks like that:

`exp<-data.frame(car=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),speed=c(10,20,30,40,50,60), maxSpeed=c(30,30,30,50,50,60))`

Maximal observed speed for Porsche was 30, so every row with Porsche will get maxSpeed = 30.

I know that it should be apply/sapply function, but have no idea how to implement it. Anyone? :)

Answer (score 2):

@Arun this is my result in a bigger sample (1000 records). The ratio of the medians is now (actually) 0.82:

```
exp <- data.frame(car=sample(1:10, 1000, T),speed=rnorm(1000, 20, 5))

f1 <- function() mutate(exp, maxSpeed = ave(speed, car, FUN=max))
f2 <- function() transform(exp, maxSpeed = ave(speed, car, FUN=max))

library(microbenchmark)
library(plyr)
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
 expr     min      lq  median       uq      max neval
 f1() 551.321 565.112 570.565 589.9680 27866.23  1000
 f2() 662.933 683.138 689.552 713.7665 28510.24  1000
```

the `plyr` documentation itself says `Mutate seems to be considerably faster than transform for large data frames.`

However, for this case, you're probably right. If I enlarge the sample:

```
> exp <- data.frame(car=sample(1:1000, 100000, T),speed=rnorm(100000, 20, 5))
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 37.92438 39.00056 40.66607 41.18115 77.41645   100
 f2() 39.47731 40.28650 43.11927 43.70779 78.34878   100
```

The ratio gets close to one. To be honest I was quite sure about `plyr` perfomance (always rely on it in my codes), that's why my 'claim' in the comment. Probably in different situation it performs better..

EDIT:

using `f3()` from @Arun comment

```
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), times=100)
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 38.76050 39.57129 41.48728 42.14812 76.94338   100
 f2() 40.38913 41.19767 44.12329 44.78782 79.94021   100
 f3() 38.63606 39.58700 40.24272 42.04902 76.07551   100
```

Yep! slightly faster... moves less data?

Comment: (+1) great! thanks a lot for doing this. I hadn't known this before. How about: `f3 <- function() { exp[["maxSpeed"]] <- with(exp, ave(speed, car, FUN=max)); exp }`.

Comment: Again, thanks! I was just editing it myself. It's faster on both small and large data. I guess both the function call overload from `transform` and the `$` overload in `exp$maxSpeed` (using `exp[["maxSpeed"]]`) helps improve *a lot*.

Comment: @Arun check the other answer with `data.table` I got 5 ms against 40...Tomorrow I'll definitely see what I can improve in my works with that package!

Comment: check the posts tagged `[data.table]` (use square brackets to search tags) and watch the magic :).

Comment: @Arun, I would search for `[r] data.table` instead as that will also give questions not tagged by data.table but that have used it in answers.   Michele, you might want to also search for `[r] data.table plyr' and you will find several examples of speed gains

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! They all work, R is crazy! :)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, yes indeed. that'd result in more hits as there are plenty of wonderful answers that aren't tagged data.table.

Answer (score 2):

very straight forward with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

exp <- data.table(exp)
exp[, maxSpeed := max(speed), by=car]
```

which gives:

```
exp
   car speed maxSpeed
1:   1    10       30
2:   1    20       30
3:   1    30       30
4:   2    40       50
5:   2    50       50
6:   3    60       60
```

Comment: a thunderbolt!! I compared your code with those in my answer and yours takes `4.983214 milliseconds`.

Comment: @Michele, it's very clear `data.table` will be faster. `data.table` preallocates columns ( `max(2*ncol(dt), 100)` IIRC). Type `truelength(exp)` and you'll get 100 (for 100 columns). And also `:=` assigns values by reference. It'll be extremely fast. However, I wanted to provide a **base** solution.

Comment: @Arun I know! Just as simple as the question was, (for simple I mean `base` is the first package anyone knows first). Anyway, it's in moments like this that I'm glad to have joined this website, thanks for your 'low level programming' Lesson! Still lots to learn!

Comment: @Michele, as Arun points out, the magic of `data.table` is that it makes great effort to not make superfluous copies of objects and to assign by reference whenever possible. This allows for insane speeds as data gets large.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! They all work, R is crazy! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(exp, maxSpeed = ave(speed, car, FUN=max))
```

---

Another way using `split`:

```
exp$maxSpeed <- exp$speed
split(exp$maxSpeed, exp$car) <- lapply(split(exp$maxSpeed, exp$car), max)
exp
```

Comment: +1 best practice of `ave`. And using `mutate` from `plyr` it would be 30% faster. Tested with `microbenchmark` package.

Comment: that's surprising to me. would you mind posting plye solution and benchmarking results (with a relatively bigger data)?

Comment: Just answered with perfomance details. Your surprise was actually legitimate! :-)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! They all work, R is crazy! :)